# Why does the str.next! in an Enumerable#map fill the array with same elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashtable

`Enumerable#map` creates an array with the return values in the block after it's yielded.

In such case, say:

```
v = 'a'
26.times.map { |i| v.ord.+(i).chr }

# => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

But why does the following codes fills the array with same elements?

```
v = '`'
26.times.map { v.next! }

# => ["z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z"]
```

```
v = '`'
Array.new(26) { v.next! }

# => ["z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z"]
```

Shouldn't they all have elements a to z?

Again, this works:

```
v = '`'
Array.new(26) { v = v.succ }

# => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

Actually I am trying to do:

```
v = "\xf0\x9d\x93\xa9"
('a'..'z').reduce({}) { |h, i| h.merge(i.intern => v = v.succ) }

# => {:a=>"", :b=>"", :c=>"", :d=>"", :e=>"", :f=>"", :g=>"", :h=>"", :i=>"", :j=>"", :k=>"", :l=>"", :m=>"", :n=>"", :o=>"", :p=>"", :q=>"", :r=>"", :s=>"", :t=>"", :u=>"", :v=>"", :w=>"", :x=>"", :y=>"", :z=>""}
```

But I get all z's instead while using `succ!` / `next!`

```
v = "\xf0\x9d\x93\xa9"
('a'..'z').reduce({}) { |h, i| h.merge(i.intern => v.succ!) }

# => {:a=>"", :b=>"", :c=>"", :d=>"", :e=>"", :f=>"", :g=>"", :h=>"", :i=>"", :j=>"", :k=>"", :l=>"", :m=>"", :n=>"", :o=>"", :p=>"", :q=>"", :r=>"", :s=>"", :t=>"", :u=>"", :v=>"", :w=>"", :x=>"", :y=>"", :z=>""}
```

Except `succ!` / `next!` doesn't change the memory location and object_id, aren't `v.succ!` and `v = v.succ` same?

Comment: Regarding your problem: `(:a..:z).zip(''..'').to_h` seems much easier.

Comment: Yeah, that's cool!

But why doesn't the bang method work while the assignment operator works?

Comment: It works, but you have an array referencing the same object 26 times instead of an array with 26 different objects. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `next!` or `succ!` on a variable `str`, object assigned to this variable is mutated and a reference to this object is returned. If `str = 'a'` and you call `str.next!` 26 times, str becomes `z`. Every time `next!` is called, a reference to the same object is returned. As a result, you get an array of 26 references to the same object. That's why all of the elements in the array are the same.

You can test that by checking `object_id` of array elements:

```
pry(main)> str = 'a'
'a'
pry(main)> array = 3.times.map{ str.next!}
=> ["d", "d", "d"]
pry(main)> array.map(&:object_id)
=> [47056742362940, 47056742362940, 47056742362940]
pry(main)> array.map(&:object_id).uniq
=> [47056742362940]
```

When you edit `str`, all array elements are updated:

```
[39] pry(main)> str << "b"
=> "db"
[40] pry(main)> array
=> ["db", "db", "db"]
[41] pry(main)> str.replace
str.replace
[41] pry(main)> str.replace('a')
=> "a"
[42] pry(main)> array
=> ["a", "a", "a"]
```

If you want to have an array with the whole alphabet, you need to copy the string after changing current letter, see below:

```
[25] pry(main)> str = 'a'
=> "a"
[26] pry(main)> 25.times.map{ str.next!.dup} 
=> ["b",
 "c",
 "d",
 "e",
 "f",
 "g",
 "h",
 "i",
 "j",
 "k",
 "l",
 "m",
 "n",
 "o",
 "p",
 "q",
 "r",
 "s",
 "t",
 "u",
 "w",
 "x",
 "y",
 "z"]
```

You can also use a range:

```
[32] pry(main)> ('a'..'z').to_a
=> ["a",
 "b",
 "c",
 "d",
 "e",
 "f",
...
```

Comment: Oh that's awesome! So in that case when you assign the array to say `a`, then if you write `z.replace('hello')` the whole array `a` fills with 'hello'! ... Similar to `a.fill('hello')`

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover changing the object.